# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'categoryName') in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update my category. I want to update only categoryname, categoryDescription and categoryImage inside the category data. For this, I pull the data from the API with the id I wrote in c# on the backend to show the first state of the data to the user, there is no problem there, but when I try to make changes to a data, nothing appears on the screen in the browser and the following errors appear in the console. Actually ı am new in react. How can I fix that problem?

**ERRORS**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'categoryName')
The above error occurred in the <UpdateCategory> component:
```

**My CategoryList.js**

I send the id of the category I clicked to UpdateCategory.js from here and I do the editing there.
CategoryList.js shows only my categories

```
import { Button } from "bootstrap";
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { Link, Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { CategoryContext } from "../Contexts/CategoryContext";
import "../Css/Categories.css"


export default function CategoryList() {



    const { Categories } = useContext(CategoryContext)


    const truncateOverview = (string, maxLength) => {
        if (!string) return null;
        if (string.length <= maxLength) return string;
        return `${string.substring(0, maxLength)} ...`;
    }



    return (

        <div className="categories">

            {Categories.map((category, i) => (
                
                    <Link className="category" to={`/ProductList/${category.categoryId}`} key={i}>
                        <div className="inner-category"> 

                                <div className="image-body">
                                <img src={category.categoryImage} className="image" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                
                                

                                <div className="category-body">
                                    <div>
                                        <h5 className="">{category.categoryName}</h5>
                                        <p className="">{truncateOverview(category.categoryDescription, 50)}</p>
                                        <Link to={`/UpdateCategory/${category.categoryId}`}>
                                        <button className ="btn btn-warning" variant="primary" >
                                            EDIT
                                        </button>
                                        </Link>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </Link>

            ))}



        </div>


    )
}
```

**My UpdateCategory.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import InputGroup from 'react-bootstrap/InputGroup';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import axios from 'axios';



export default function UpdateCategory() {

  const { id } = useParams()
  const url = `http://localhost:64082/api/categories/getbyid/${id}`
  const [category, setCategory] = useState({})

  const fetchData = () => {

    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        setCategory(response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    fetchData()
    
  });


  
  const handleInputChange =(e)=>{
      setCategory(e.target.category)
  }


  const handleSubmit = (event) => {

    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.target);

    fetch(`http://localhost:64082/api/categories/update`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    })

  }

 
    return (

      <div>
        <form   >
          <label htmlFor="inputName">Category Name</label>
          <input type="text"
            className="form-control"
            name="categoryName"
            value={category.categoryName}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />



          <label htmlFor="inputName">Category Description</label>
          <input type="text"
            className="form-control"
            name="categoryDescription"
            value={category.categoryDescription}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />

          <label htmlFor="inputName">Category Image</label>
          <input type="text"
            className="form-control"
            name="categoryImage"
            value={category.categoryImage}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
          <div>
            <button onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="btn btn-danger"  >EDIT</button>

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    )
  }
```

Comment: you have one handleInputChange for all the three inputs ?

Comment: yes I have only one handleInputChange for all inputs.

Comment: so when you change something ,  setCategory get triggered so the value inside category is a string  and {category.categoryName} is invalid

Comment: I understand .so how can we solve ?

Comment: If you want to access a data attribute on a custom target tag, you can use getAttribute.
`e.target.category` is not a valid accessor.

Answer (score 0):

The error probably comes about because of the render in UpdateCategory. The code tells it to render three properties of the category object. But initially, category is an empty object. So it will fail there.

There's another point you need to modify though, in the useEffect(). What you have right now will not trigger on the initialisation of the component. Change it to:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData()
}, []);
```

Since you're not using typescript you'd also probably want some kind of guard on your render to be safe. So for example something like this:

```
return category.categoryName && category.categoryDescription && category.categoryImage && (
  // your render code in here
);
```

But that's quite long-winded. You could write an if clause before the return () for the render, asking if those properties exist and returning a blank component instead, or some alternate text.

You could also perhaps provide a default version of the category when initialising the hook.

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState({
  categoryName: 'Default',
  categoryDescription: 'Default description',
  categoryImage: null
});
```

This would be a simpler effort than the guard block, and you'd still need the useEffect update.

Answer (score 0):

In UpdateCategory.js,edit;

const [category, setCategory] = useState([]) // not useState({})

The default value of this state should be an empty array. Thanks to empty array, It will not be able to return with map until data comes from api, because its length is 0.